# Imprimir fecha en pantalla con otro formato PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy modificando un código de un programa que realiza cotizaciones.
Quisiera imprimir la fecha en otro formato y no sé como hacerlo. Se muestra como Y-m-d y quiero que se vea como d-m-Y.

Paso el código:
En este formulario se genera la fecha de la cotización:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
                <input value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y")?>" name="fecha" autocomplete="off" required type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha">
            </div>
```

Aquí se guarda:

```
<?php
if (
    empty($_POST["tokenCSRF"])
    ||
    empty($_POST["idCliente"])
    ||
    empty($_POST["descripcion"])
    ||
    empty($_POST["fecha"])
) {
    exit;
}
Utiles::salirSiTokenCSRFNoCoincide($_POST["tokenCSRF"]);
Cotizaciones::nueva($_POST["idCliente"], $_POST["descripcion"], $_POST["fecha"]);
Utiles::redireccionar("cotizaciones");
```

y aquí es donde se imprime y quiero que se vea con otro formato:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm" align="center">
            <h2><strong>COTIZACION PARA <?php echo htmlentities($cotizacion->razonSocial) ?></strong></h2>
            <h4>Referencia: <?php echo htmlentities($cotizacion->descripcion) ?></h4> 
            
            <h4>Fecha: <?php echo htmlentities($cotizacion->fecha) ?></h4>
<!--            <?php if (!empty($ajustes->mensajePresentacion)): ?>
                <p><?php echo htmlentities($ajustes->mensajePresentacion) ?></p>
            <?php endif ?>  -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Desde ya agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea un objeto `DateTime` y llama al método `format`:

```php
<h4>Fecha: <?php echo (new DateTime($cotizacion->fecha))->format('d-m-Y'); ?></h4>
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo: https://web.tinkerwell.app/#/snippets/b90d44ad-278b-4164-8e6c-ad55ce878078

Answer (score 0):

ya tienes la respuesta. "creo que así debería funcionar"

```
<?php 

   date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
   echo "fecha:  " . date("d/m/Y") . "<br>". " hora: ". date("h:i:sa");

?>
```

También puedes mostrar la hora,  pero debes primero definir la zona horaria